# Is it possible to strip the magnetic, or electric field from a photon?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, magnetic-fields

A photon is made up of a magnetic part and an electric part, but we can see the existence of these fields without the other one so I would like to know if it is possible to somehow separate one field from the other and let the *half* photon keep on travelling.

Or perhaps, is there a way to shoot magnetic (or electric) waves separately?

Comment: "A photon" isn't made up of anything. It's a measurement result on a quantum field. Since all those results come in as discrete values, we call them "quanta". Quanta are not made up of fields and they are not somehow making fields. Quanta are simply the possible states of a field, but the fundamental physical "object" is an operator valued continuous field, at least in the current theory.

Answer (score 1):

Classical electricity and magnetism has been modeled successfully by [the Maxwell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field) . The domain of classical physics is macroscopic and the theory suffices for most observations. The electromagnetic waves are described very well and one of these can be written as a [potential A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation#Covariant_form_of_the_homogeneous_wave_equation) which gives rise to the electric and magnetic fields according to boundary conditions.

In this frame there are no separate electric or magnetic waves since changing electric fields per force generate magnetic fields and vice verso. This has been verified over and over and is used in all applications from radio to radar to television.

The existence of photons which make up the EM wave came from the discovery that [black body radiatio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation)n needed quantized electromagnetic carriers of energy, and also the [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) showed a particle type behavior of light on various materials.

Quantum mechanics is the mathematical theory that describes physics in the microlevel of particles, atoms, molecules,... Particles are described  by appropriate equations whose solutions , called wave functions, when squared give the probability of finding a particle in a specific (x,y,z,t) . The wavefunction that gives the probabilities for a photon is one dependent on the A potential. Each individual photon carries information on the A potential and in a beam of photons builds up the classical wave of the Maxwell equations, but this A potential exists mathematically in a complex variable space. When the function is squared, there is no dependence on electric or magnetic field for a single [photon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon). It is just a quantum of energy equal to h*nu with spin 1/-1 in its direction of motion and mass zero. It is a building block in the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics, as an elementary particle.

**Thus there is no electric or magnetic field in the description of the photon**, just a complex potential which disappears when the photon interacts/is measured to give the probability of the interaction. This is consistent with the classical limit of electromagnetic waves, which have no format of only electric or only magnetic waves, as their wave change will generate each other if one tries to do this ( for example changing a magnetic field in space by vibrating it).